# Avoid keyboard closing when iPhone rotated XCode Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

I have in left navigation item **UITextField**. When I type something in there and rotate device, keyboard hides everytime.

I tried to handle **UIKeyboardWillHideNotification**, but all what I got is: keyboard closes and shows again after that. It's not good, I need to rotate keyboard along with view...

Please help in **Swift 2**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution!
First, need to implement delegate:

```
ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Next, add to **viewDidLoad** method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self
}
```

To the end, realise **textFieldShouldEndEditing** function:

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    //here we can add some if-block for orientation change or smth else
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

The method above here gets called when the device **will** rotate, as you don't care about the orientation we don't check it and simple instruct the textfield you are editing to become first responder.

Comment: you know, it's **not working** at all...
function really gets called when the device **will** rotate.
but! after that keyboard is still hides.

how can I lock keyboard closing?